# No relation mappings are setup on my entities, can I still do this query?

Tags: nhibernate

I have 2 entities:

```
article
category
```

then a table:

```
articles_categories
- articleID
- categoryID
```

I only have mappings for article and category, and no relationships have been setup as of yet.

Is it possible to build a query to get all articles that are in categoryID=234 ?

Comment: You could, of course, use a native query and just write the SQL yourself since you know what the schema looks like.  But you might as well just take the time to map the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (using HQL queries).  If `article` contained a `categoryID` field then you would be able to do it, but with a many-to-many relationship table, you'll need to set up the mappings.

It might be possible if you use a [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).  But setting up the relationship is the proper thing to do.